# when trying to edit new profile is creating in django

Tags: python, django, edit, profile

i am a beginner. my project is regarding the companies and customers. i have created, profile page for them. now i want to create an edit page such that companies can edit their profile. 
my model is:

```
class Company_Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(_('Company Name'), max_length= 30)
    logo = models.FileField(_('Company Logo'), upload_to=get_upload_file_name, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(_('Contact Address'), max_length=50)
    phone_no = models.IntegerField(_('Contact No'), max_length=12) 

class Customer_Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), max_length= 30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(_('Middle Name'), max_length= 30,null =True,blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), max_length= 30)
    photo = models.ImageField(_('Photo'), upload_to=get_upload_file_name,   null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(_('Contact Address'), max_length=50)
    phone_no = models.IntegerField(_('Contact No'), max_length=12)
```

my views.py is:

```
def register(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       user = User.objects.create_user(
       username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
       password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
       email=form.cleaned_data['email']
        )
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
  else:
    form = RegistrationForm()
  catagories = Company_Profile.objects.all()
  customers = Customer_Profile.objects.all()
  return render_to_response('index1.html',
                      {'form': form, 'catagories': catagories,     'customers' : customers},RequestContext(request))

def edit_company(request, offset):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    company_edit = update_company_prof(request.POST)
    if company_edit.is_valid():
       company_edit.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect('company/'+str(offset))
  else:
     company_edit = update_company_prof(instance = request.user.company_profile)
  return render_to_response('edit_comp_prof.html', {'company_edit': company_edit}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my html page is:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{ company_edit.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Update" />
 <input type="reset" class="btn" value="cancel">
</form>
```

my edit form is:

```
class update_company_prof(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company_Profile
        fields =     ('name','logo','address','phone_no','cat_software','cat_electronics','cat_mechanical','cat_civil','cat_other','specialized_in','prev_projects')
```

when i submit it, a new company profile is created instead of editing. what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the `instance` argument to the form's constructor in the `method == 'POST'` branch:

```
company_edit = update_company_prof(request.POST,
                                   instance=request.user.company_profile)
```